# Eclipse plugin to measure programmer performance/stats

Tags: eclipse, metrics

Does anyone know of an Eclipse plugin that can give me some stats about my behaviour/usage of the Eclipse IDE?

There are quite a few things I would like to know:

- How often/when do I invoke the "Build All" command (through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
- How often does compilation fail/succeed (+ number of errors/warnings)
- How often do I hit Backspace? (I do that way to often; If pressing that key would give a nasty sound I would in time learn to type correctly in the first place)
- How many characters/lines of code that I typed do I delete (possibly quite immediately)
- How (effective/efficient/...) is my Mouse/Keyboard/IDE usage? (Kinda like measuring APM in StarCraft; this could be fun)

If there is no such Eclipse plugin around, how complex and time consuming would It be to write a plugin that can accomplish the above?

**edit:**
I am interested in these usage stats since I noticed that a good IDE and a fast computer strongly influenced my behaviour when coding over the past years.

I use Content Assist all the time, its very practical but now I notice, that I would be totally unable to get anything done without it.

Hitting Backspace has become almost a reflex :) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+B</kbd> almost too.</kbd>

I now routinely hit Ctrl+B to do an incremental build sometimes even after changing a few lines, so that the compiler gives immediate feedback and since compiling is quite fast nowadays it works quite well. This keeps me from actually having to think on my own, when I do stuff wrong, I now rely on the compiler to spot the errors, I have become worse at spotting them myself since I don't really need to do that any longer.

Did you guys notice these changes in yourself too?

Answer (score 1):

The best tool in this area(in my opinion) for eclipse is [Lack of Progress Bar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lopb/) ,it doesn't have all the feature that you request, but allow to measure the developer performance and the bottlenecks of the development process.

**What is Lopb?**

> Lack of Progress Bar (Lopb) is an Eclipse plugin that tracks how long
>   developers wait for background jobs to complete. By benchmarking the
>   performance of background jobs, Lopb provides developers with metrics
>   on how much of their day was wasted due to overhead introduced by the
>   development tools and infrastructure that they depend on or access
>   through their IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mousefeed](http://www.mousefeed.com/), it will help you move from using the mouse to keyboard. Not sure if it can keep stats of your usage.

As for other stats, look at [Usage Data Collector](http://eclipse.org/epp/usagedata/), it will keep track of all Eclipse usage, favorite view, perspective usage, most common errors, etc.

Dont know of anyone that actually keeps track of how you type in the editor, but why would you want that? Part of the development process is to change things alot imho. Focus on the end result instead and look at some [static code analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730433/recommended-eclipse-plugins-for-java-source-code-analysis).